# EXCEL VBA run time error 91 -Object not set

Tags: excel, vba, set, runtime

VBA excel run time error Object not set error 91.

Unfortunately I can't debug and locate the line that causes the bug because the bug does not appear in the original xlsm file, it appears only after compiling the file into native Windows DLL with code obscuring (created with trail version of [vbacompiler](https://vbacompiler.com) software).

```
    Public Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ResultString As Date
  'Open DateTimePicker userform if user selects
    If Not Intersect(Target, WhatsAppMsg.Range(F1_DateToSend & "4:" & F1_DateToSend & 9999)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.CountLarge > 30 Then Exit Sub
    ResultString = frmDateTimePicker.SelectedDateTime
        If VBA.Len(ResultString) > 10 Then
               Selection.Value = ResultString
               Selection.Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
       End If
End sub

 Public Function SelectedDateTime(Optional ByVal Target_Control As Object) As String

    Dim str As String

    If (VBA.TypeName(Target_Control)) = "TextBox" Or VBA.TypeName(Target_Control) = "Range" Then str = Target_Control.Value
    If (VBA.TypeName(Target_Control)) = "CommandButton" Or VBA.TypeName(Target_Control) = "Label" Then str = Target_Control.Caption

    If VBA.IsDate(str) Then
        Me.TextBox1.Value = VBA.Format(VBA.CDate(str), "dd/mm/yy")
        Else
        Me.TextBox1.Value = VBA.Format(VBA.Date, "dd/mm/yy")
    End If

    Me.Show

    If (VBA.TypeName(Target_Control)) = "TextBox" Or VBA.TypeName(Target_Control) = "Range" Then
         Target_Control.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
    ElseIf (VBA.TypeName(Target_Control)) = "CommandButton" Or TypeName(Target_Control) = "Label" Then
         Target_Control.Caption = Me.TextBox1.Value
    Else
        SelectedDateTime = Me.TextBox1.Value
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Maybe the developer of `vbacompliler` can help. You might also be able to track things down by inserting `debug.print` lines within your code, and seeing what prints out when you run the dll.

Comment: the bug is in ResultString = frmDateTimePicker.SelectedDateTime

Comment: Maybe something with how vbacompiler interacts with forms. I've never used that program, though.  Perhaps if you include the code generated after compilation, someone here might have an idea.  Or could check with the program developers.

Comment: I need to pass the Selected cell to  Target_Control As Object instead of ignoring it because it is optional. maybe It should not be optional